# How to upload large files to GCP Cloud Storage using .Net client library

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to upload large files to Google Cloud Storage bucket from [.Net Client library](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest), but I can't find any method for multi part upload.

However, I see there is a way to upload large files using [Parallel composite uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/parallel-composite-uploads). But looks like it's available only for command line tools and JSON and XML apis.

Is there any implementation for the same in the .Net client or any other alternative?

Comment: You can't use `client.UploadObject(` method?

Comment: The client library doesn't support parallel composite uploads, but you should be able to upload large files with `client.UploadObject`. If that doesn't work for you, please provide more information in the post.

Comment: I am using `client.UploadObjectAsync` method as of now. I have tested upto 10GB files and was able to upload. Just curious what is the max size limit. I saw it's 2GB is the documentation.

Comment: I shared my solution, can you have a look at it?

Comment: @Yasitha: Where did you see it supposedly documented as having a 2GB limit? That sounds like something that needs fixing (unless you've misinterpreted a different constraint). (If it's the "Upload size specifications" section [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#size), that's not documenting a constraint of the maximum file size - it's about considering "the amount of time that you're willing to lose should a network failure occur and you need to restart the upload from the beginning". (But the .NET client library uses resumable uploads anyway, always.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads)  methods for JSON and XML APIs and also for [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#client-libraries) like node.js, C++,Go,Java,PHP, Python and Ruby.

As per comment [Upload size specifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#size) :
You can upload and store any MIME type of data up to 5 TiB and If you upload from an in-region service that averages 500 Mbps for its upload speed, the cutoff size for files is almost 2 GB.

Comment: Note that the piece of documentation you're quoting is about single-request uploads, whereas the .NET client library *always* uses resumable uploads.